# How to open a database after reinstalling SQL Server 17.9.1

Tags: database, sql-server

I had to reinstall SQL Server. Now when I try to create a new database if says database already exists although it doesnt show any user databases in the Object Explorer.

Question is: How can I get these databases back in Object Explorer OR delete them so I can create them again from scratch. I tried deleting the folder where the DB's are located but its protected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Load SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the required instance (I assume it's localhost)
3. Expand the Instance tree on the left, in Object Explorer
4. Right-click on 'Databases'
5. Choose 'Attach...'
6. Click 'Add...'
7. Browse to your .MDF
8. Click OK
9. Click OK on 'Attach Databases'

Your database should now show on the left under Databases in Object Explorer.